# CSS3 Border Radius e Background no IE 11

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, css-border-radius

Olá, estou enfrentando um problema com border-radius e background no Internet Explorer 11, ele coloca uma leve borda branca, neste caso, ela fica em cima do border-shadow, porém, se eu tirar os efeitos do box-shadow, continua uma sombra azul quase branca em baixo do botão.

[image: Problema no botão e CSS associado]

Alguém já passou por isso e tenha idéia de como resolver?

Comment: É só um palpite, mas, você viu isso? _" Para obter box-shadow no IE9ou superior, é preciso definir border-collapse como separate."_ [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: @Pablo isso não resolveu

Comment: Se você atribui esse CSS a outras tags, o problema persiste? Talvez seja alguma coisa de CSS que o IE tá atribuindo pro conta própria pra uma tag específica.